# DisconnectedContext detected when using STA thread to modify SharePoint page

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Background Info: I'm using an ItemCheckedIn receiver in SharePoint 2010, targeting .NET 3.5 Framework. The goal of the receiver is to:

1. Make sure the properties (columns) of the page match the data in a Content Editor WebPart on the page so that the page can be found in a search using Filter web parts. The pages are automatically generated, so barring any errors they are guaranteed to fit the expected format.
2. If there is a mismatch, check out the page, fix the properties, then check it back in.

I've kept the receiver from falling into an infinite check-in/check-out loop, although right now it's a very clumsy fix that I'm trying to work on. However, right now I can't work on it because I'm getting a DisconnectedContext error whenever I hit the UpdatePage function:

```
public override void ItemCheckedIn(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    // If the main page or machine information is being checked in, do nothing
    if (properties.AfterUrl.Contains("home") || properties.AfterUrl.Contains("machines")) return;

    // Otherwise make sure that the page properties reflect any changes that may have been made
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://san1web.net.jbtc.com/sites/depts/VPC/"))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPFile page = web.GetFile(properties.AfterUrl);

        // Make sure the event receiver doesn't get called infinitely by checking version history
        ...

        UpdatePage(page);
    }
}

private static void UpdatePage(SPFile page)
{
    bool checkOut = false;

    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
        using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            // Get web part's contents into HtmlDocument
            ContentEditorWebPart cewp = (ContentEditorWebPart)manager.WebParts[0];

            HtmlDocument htmlDoc;
            wb.Navigate("about:blank");
            htmlDoc = wb.Document;
            htmlDoc.OpenNew(true);
            htmlDoc.Write(cewp.Content.InnerText);

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                // Check that each property matches the information on the page
                string element;
                try
                {
                    element = htmlDoc.GetElementById(prop).InnerText;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (!element.Equals(page.GetProperty(prop).ToString()))
                {
                    if (!prop.Contains("Request"))
                    {
                        checkOut = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (!element.Equals(page.GetProperty(prop).ToString().Split(' ')[0]))
                    {
                        checkOut = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!checkOut) return;

            // If there was a mismatch, check the page out and fix the properties
            page.CheckOut();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                page.SetProperty(prop, htmlDoc.GetElementById(prop).InnerText);
                page.Item[prop] = htmlDoc.GetElementById(prop).InnerText;

                try
                {
                    page.Update();
                }
                catch
                {
                    page.SetProperty(prop, Convert.ToDateTime(htmlDoc.GetElementById(prop).InnerText).AddDays(1));
                    page.Item[prop] = Convert.ToDateTime(htmlDoc.GetElementById(prop).InnerText).AddDays(1);
                    page.Update();
                }
            }

            page.CheckIn("");
        }
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}
```

From what I understand, using a WebBrowser is the only way to fill an HtmlDocument in this version of .NET, so that's why I have to use this thread.

In addition, I've done some reading and it looks like the DisconnectedContext error has to do with threading and COM, which are subjects I know next to nothing about. What can I do to prevent/fix this error?

**EDIT**

As @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets pointed out in the comments, I could insert an editable field bound to the page column and not worry about parsing any html, but because the current page layout uses an HTML table within a Content Editor WebPart, where this kind of field wouldn't work properly, I'd need to make a new page layout and rebuild my solution from the bottom up, which I would really rather avoid.

I'd also like to avoid downloading anything, as the company I work for normally doesn't allow the use of unapproved software.

Comment: Are you trying to parse html markup in code? If so you shouldn't do this with WebBrowser class which is part of Windows Forms and is not suited for web as well as for pure html parsing. Try using some html parser like HtmlAgilityPack (https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Another question is why are you trying to fill properties of the page programmatically? If you are using SharePoint Page Layouts then you can add to page layout editable field which is bound to page's field.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Would those editable fields be bound to the properties, i.e. a user changes a value on the page and the corresponding column is updated? If so, that would remove the need for me to even use this event receiver, which I think is much more ideal.

Comment: Yes, it would. You can see example of simple single line of text field in standard article layout.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets Using the HtmlAgilityPack worked. Mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok, i'll do that. Just out of curiosity, have you tried bound fields as i mentioned?

Comment: Ok, i see your edit to post, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do html parsing with WebBrowser class which is part of Windows Forms and is not suited for web as well as for pure html parsing. Try using some html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.